# Does the PVV want to stop all support for Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, parties, netherlands, foreign-aid, fact-check-request

[*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/nov/23/dutch-election-results-geert-wilders-party-for-freedom-europe-latest-news):

> The European Greens said today that if VVD joins a coalition with Geert Wilders’ far-right PVV, it should be expelled from the Alliance of Liberals and Democrats for Europe (ALDE).
>
> Thomas Waitz and Mélanie Vogel, co-chairs of the European Green party, said in a statement that “the VVD has a big responsibility when it comes to possible future government coalitions”.
>
> They added:
>
> > Will they choose for a democratic coalition? Or will they embrace a coalition with a far-right party that wants to kill climate policy, to leave the European Union, **stop all support to Ukraine**, and strip minorities in the Netherlands of their rights?

Is stopping all support for Ukraine an official or quasi-official plank of the PVV?

I see that when the war started Wilders [tweeted](https://twitter.com/geertwilderspvv/status/1496846732612800514?s=20):

> Do not let Dutch households pay the price for a war that is not ours.

Has the PVV been consistent on that position since then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PVV party program](https://www.pvv.nl/images/2023/PVV-Verkiezingsprogramma-2023.pdf?__cf_chl_tk=X8jfXQdgiVWfATVS9jKt3SG1aZAdKF22hPJRnwQ0WcQ-1700775873-0-gaNycGzNCrs) ([published in September 2023](https://www.parlement.com/id/vm6l9s89i7xf/nieuws/pvv_presenteert_verkiezingsprogramma_met)) mentions Ukraine four times. In the section on defense (on pages 36-37) it says:

> Terwijl onze Krijgsmacht niet eens meer in staat is om het eigen grondgebied te verdedigen, sturen we ons schaarse materieel naar Oekraïne. Onze nationale verdediging wordt dus ernstig verzwakt, omdat het kabinet ook hier het buitenland belangrijker vinden dan ons eigen land.

and

> We sturen ons geld en Defensie- materieel zoals F16’s niet naar Oekraïne
> maar houden het voor onze eigen Krijgsmacht

That translates to (my translation)

> While our armed forces aren't even in a state to defend our own territory, we send our scarce materiel to Ukraine. Our national defense is thus seriously impaired, because the cabinet here too prioritizes abroad above our own country.

and

> We don't send our money and defense materiel such as F16s to Ukraine but we keep it for our own armed forces.

Ukraine is also mentioned in the foreign affairs section, EU and development aid section of the program. The paragraph (on page 42) containing the mentions reads:

> De bevolking van Afrika groeit deze eeuw tot ruim 4 miljard inwoners en is door corrupte heersende klassen gedoemd tot armoede en oorlogsellende.
> De nu al aanwezige tsunami van gelukszoekers naar Europa zal daardoor alleen
> nog maar verder aanzwellen. Aan de oostzijde van Europa woedt een grote
> oorlog tussen Rusland en Oekraïne, nadat de Russische agressor onrechtmatig
> Oekraïne is binnengevallen.

That translates to (my translation):

> The population of Africa grows this century beyond 4 billion inhabitants and is doomed to poverty and war misery by corrupt ruling classes. The already present tsunami of fortune seekers to Europe will therefore only grow. In the east side of Europe a large war rages between Russia and Ukraine, after the Russian agressor unlawfully entered Ukraine.

So it mentions stopping aid in the form of money and military materiel. In the last paragraph we find that the PVV does label Russia as the agressor in the war.

Comment: "unlawfully entered", it feels that their tone regarding Russia is milder than other nations...